What film starts with a home invasion and turns into S&M horror; 80's or early 90's (*not* People Under the Stairs)?
Film starts with two men armed with shotguns committing a push-in robbery against what seems to be a normal suburban family. Early on, they have the family tied to chairs. Somehow the family gets free and it is revealed that the robbers have found a family of sadists who have a dungeon in the basement. Mayhem ensues. My memory is fuzzy on the details, but I remember the mood being dark and violent, similar to Last House on the Left, or maybe Martyrs. I rented it from Video Station in Boulder CO (probably TMI), pretty sure it was a DVD, the cover had a headshot of the two robbers, and it was billed like a straight crime film. The title might have been the names of the robbers.
I've been trying to find this film for decades...please help Internet!

It sounds similar to Funny Games, but not quite. You might find it on Wikipedia's List of films featuring home invasions.

I think it's Killers, also known as Real Killers released in 1996.
From http://forcedviewing.com/2013/05/14/real-killers-movie-review-by-john-bruni/

Odessa and Kyle James are killers and media darlings very much in the
  same vein as the Menendez brothers.  One day, they dressed up as
  clowns and shotgunned their parents, who were asleep at the time. 
  After a media circus involving many interviews and a lot of
  speculation as to whether or not their parents sexually abused them,
  they are convicted and manage to escape from prison.  On the run, they
  bust in on the Ryan family and take them hostage, hoping to evade the
  authorities.
The Ryan family—father Charles, mother Rea, and daughters Jami and
  Jenny—seem like the average American family, but as the film goes
  along, we find out more and more about them until they seem like
  complete strangers. 
...the Ryans have a major surprise for the James brothers, but it’s
  not the one you think.  You see, there’s a fifth member of the family:
  Bob, an effeminate mutant monster who has romantic intentions toward
  Kyle.  Oh yeah, and the Ryans have a F***ING DUNGEON under their
  house, where they keep all sorts of humanoid monsters.  Before you
  know it, the James brothers are stuck in a shoot out with the dungeon
  folks in an attempt to survive this cluster**** of a home invasion.

One version of the movie poster:

Another version:

